# Retrieve a value from either mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table a and b, each have an average field in them. Data is inserted into only one of the tables at a time so either of the average fields can remain null at one given time. How can i retrieve the value in either of the fields in the two tables which is not null

```
Table a
id  average labref
1   325      123

Table b
id  average labref
2    null    123
```

If table a is the one with the average value, i pick that value and if next time table b is the a with the average value and table one is average is null, i pick the value of table a. They both have same id used called labref!

Comment: What is the correlation between the tables? Should they match on id? Do the id's exist in both tables? (having a value of NULL in avarage is different from having no record at all).

Comment: The tables have a same value called labref field which contains the same value

Comment: Gomez, have set the fields to null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select average from (
select average from tablea
union
select average from tableb) a

where average is not null
```

OR

```
select CASE WHEN a.average is null then b.average else a.average end average from tablea a inner join table b 
on a.labref=b.labref
```

Comment: Note that the first query will only return **distinct** values of average (so that if the same average figure is recorded for multiple labrefs, that average will only be returned once), while the second query will only return averages where the same labref is recorded in **both** tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    IF(a.average IS NULL, b.average, a.average) AS average 
FROM 
    a, b 
where a.id = b.id
```

Comment: You can just use `IFNULL` or the more generic `COALESCE`.

Comment: Yup...just for knowledge, which one is better in performance ? `ternary IF`, `IFNULL` or `COALESCE` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select labref, max(average) from
(select labref, average from a union all 
 select labref, average from b) ab
group by labref
```

Comment: It will probably work, but there are better options that show more clearly what is going on and will probably perform better on large tables as well.

Comment: @GolezTrol: A join is likely to perform much worse than a union for large tables.

Comment: @GolezTrol: No, unioning is still likely to perform better even with grouping.

Answer (score -1):

Could you use the IFNOTNULL() function in the following way :

```
select IFNOTNULL(average,(select average from b)) from a
```

I havent tested this and am going off the top of my head.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
select average from a, b where a.average IS NOT NULL and b.average IS NOT NULL
```

i am not sure of to use `IS NOT NULL` two times or not.